# Updating two column values into another column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I would like to add together two values from a table and update it into another column.

For example, I have the columns `Money1` and `Money2`, I want to total them and insert the value into `TotalMoney`

I've tried various queries but all of them failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET TotalMoney = Money1 + Money2;
```

should do it.

Comment: Hey, no problem, I'm glad it helped you out.  Don't forget to accept and/or upvote the answer if it was useful :)

Comment: Okay.  In that case, I think accepting it is still an option, 15 minutes after it was asked :)